# NSTextField - how to change size and position of text/editing area?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

Well, I got this: http://d.pr/i/jItM

I obviously want to move text down and away from left edge. I have subclass of NSTextField where I draw the background, but I wasnt able to find out this.

Comment: So I have managed to position text as I want when not editing. However when I start editing text it moves back to the top left corner! I have no idea how to position fieldEditor, I tried override various methods in NSTextFieldCell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. Both needs to be overriden.

```
- (void)editWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject event:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    aRect.origin.y += 9;
    aRect.origin.x += 10;
    [super editWithFrame:aRect inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject event:theEvent];
}

- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength
{
    aRect.origin.y += 9;
    aRect.origin.x += 10;
    [super selectWithFrame:aRect inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject start:selStart length:selLength];
}
```